# Models in Django are not showing

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I am trying to add another model in django admin, called Posts. I have few other modules that are working and showing, but I don t know why this new one down not appear. Below is my code

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

STATUS = ((0, "Draft"), (1, "Published"))


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=1048)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_lenght=1048)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    content = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Application, Message, FloaterMessage

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Message)
admin.site.register(FloaterMessage)
admin.site.register(Application)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'visionStudios',
    'contact',
    'crispy_forms'
]
```

Here is the maigration, I think

```
    from django.db import migrations, models

    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    STATUS = ((0,  "Draft"), (1, "Published"))

    class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
    ('contact'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Post',
        fields=[
            ('title',  models.CharField(max_lenght=1048)),
            ('slug', models.SlugField(max_lenght=1048)),
            ('author', models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')),
            ('content', models.TextField()),
            ('status', models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

I want to be shown in Django admin

Comment: "Show" where exactly…?

Comment: did you migrate??

Comment: How a correct migrations is done? Just one thing to add, I am using digitalocean as server

Comment: `./manage.py migrate`. If other models are showing (in the admin, I guess), you've already done that once. BTW have you added the app to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: the app is installed, it's called contact

Comment: @deceze I made your modifications, still not working

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in development and you don't care loosing the data in your database just delete the database and migrations folder in the 'Post' model containing app and run `python manage.py makemigrations <app name here>` then `python manage.py migrate <app name here>`